# regexp doesn't match can't find numbers in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

By some reason js cannot match my string with regexp

```
            href = "/admin/user/manage/621/edit";
            var myRegexp = new RegExp("/user\/manage\/([0-9]+)/g");
            var match = myRegexp.exec(href);
            console.log(match)
```

tried different combinations still null as result. What is wrong?

Comment: Remove the quotes around the regex pattern.

Comment: test your regexp on https://regexr.com. Test if the regex is working by adding a very simple regex that you are sure will match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `RegExp` constructor does not work like regular expression literals. If you want to provide a g flag, it must be the second argument:

```js
var myRegexp = new RegExp("user/manage/([0-9]+)", "g");
```

or, just use a regex literal:

```js
var myRegexp = /user\/manage\/([0-9]+)/g;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing up the `RegExp` constructor and the regex literal syntax. You must use either, but not combine them.

The constructor, without the slashes to delimet the regex and the flags as second argument:

```
var re = new RegExp('user/manage/([0-9]+)', 'g');
```

or as regex literal with slash delimiting the expression and the flags following immediately the closing delimiter:

```
var re = /user\/manage\/([0-9]+)/g;
```

---

When you write `new RegExp("/user\/manage\/([0-9]+)/g")`, you create a regular expression that matches a string starting with a slash and ending with the letter g. For instance `"/user/manage/123/g"` would be matched by your regex.